# Ambiguous column name - whats wrong with the syntax here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I cant seem to figure out what is wrong with the SQL here, when an asterisk (*) is included in the SELECT statement. eg:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, createdon, * from Person
Where firstname like '%J%'
Order By createdon desc
```

I get 'Ambiguous column name 'CreatedOn'. error.

However without the (*) where its not returning the remainder of the columns it works fine.

Any suggestion or workaround?

Comment: `Order By 3 desc` because that is the 3rd column in the select.

Comment: remove the * and list each of the fields you want displayed.  the parser can not resolve the * createdon and the enumerated createdon

Comment: Recommended reading, @shahkalpesh : [Bad Habits to Kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: @Larnu: Thank you. I suggested this as a workaround and am assuming this maybe one off sql and not something that would be part of stored proc/functions.

Comment: Using article suggested by @Larnu, one can do `SELECT firstname, lastname, created = createdon , * from Person Where firstname like '%J%' Order By created desc`

Comment: Honestly, like I mention in my answer, @shahkalpesh, the better™ solution is to get rid of the `*` and be explicit on the columns you want returned; then you *can't* have ambiguous columns unless you intentionally alias 2 columns with the same alias.

Comment: @shahkalpesh No, that's a bad idea, because now anyone who ever maintains the code in the future has to know that if they change the SELECT list in any way they also have to change the arbitrary number used in the ORDER BY. And it's not the kind of breakage you will catch in a unit test, because it won't fail, it will just behave differently. And IMHO it is not a good solution to return `CreatedOn` twice with two different aliases just to keep `*`. The right answer is to stop using `*` and only return each column once.

Comment: I might point out that you only get this error if the `SELECT` is actually a subquery or derived table or CTE, not if it's an individual statement. So you haven't actually given us a [mcve]

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Appreciate that people like you and others are commenting and giving the right advice. I am assuming that this will be a one off scenario and why would somebody use a column as well as *

Answer (score 2):

`createdon` is in the returned dataset twice, once from the explicit call, and once from the `*`. As such there are 2 columns with the name `createdon` and so `ORDER BY createdon` is ambiguous; do you want to order by the first column named `createdon` or the second one (the fact that they would have same value is irrelevant, as SQL Server just sees 2 columns with the same name).

Really, you shouldn't be using `SELECT *` and should be defining all your columns; I don't see a need to return 3 of columns twice. But what you can do if you "must" have 2 copies of the same column is to prefix the one in the `ORDER BY` with the table name/alias; this would then refer to the column "in" the table, not the one in the result set (of which there are 2). I use an alias here:

```sql
SELECT P.firstname,
       P.lastname,
       P.createdon,
       * --Replace this with the actual columns you need, don't be lazy
FROM dbo.Person P
WHERE P.firstname like '%J%'
ORDER BY P.createdon DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you are selecting "createdon" column twice and but ordering the results by "one of them. The SQL interpreter doesn't understand which "createdon" column it needs to sort the result and so Ambiguous column name is returned. You can solve this by using aliasing one of the "createdon" in the selected statement.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure but try with that

SELECT firstname, lastname, createdon createdon2, * from Person
Where firstname like '%J%'
Order By createdon desc